# How to migrate webmin users to a new webmin installation

Tags: webmin

I have webmin on Redhat Linux 5.11 and I have installed webmin 1.870 installed on Redhat Linux 7.4.  I want to migrate the webmin users from the existing webmin installation to the new webmin installation.  I could not find instructions in the webmin documentation or Internet search.

Answer (score 0):

Webmin stores its users in `/etc/webmin/miniserv.users` file.

After editing this file you would have to restart *miniserv* by running:

```
 /etc/webmin/restart
```

Comment: You say I need to edit the miniserv.users file.  Are you suggesting all I need to do is copy the webmin users I want from the existing miniserv.users file to the new miniserv.users file and then restart?

Comment: As far as I understood, you don't mean user data but only user's login credential, then yes.